# Wondering if i can pass table name as parameter in EF CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

i am wondering if i can pass table name as Parameter in EF CORE.

This is static example:

```
        var post = await factory.Posts.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

i define table staticlly here as "factory.Posts"

but.. i would want to pass this dynamically in parameter.

This is example (not working)

```
public async Task Accept(int id,Type type)
        {
            if (type == typeof(PostEntity))
            {
                using var factory = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
                var post = await factory.type.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
                post!.IsVerified = true;
                await factory.SaveChangesAsync();

            }

            }
```

Comment: you can simply use the method factory.Set<T>()

Comment: That not _really_ "passing a table name", though. The table name _could_ be different. But I guess what you want is "by type" - which brings us to Generics, which is supported by EF Core.

Comment: this is not working. look at this: imgur.com/tXWtEXE . @type variable is passed from admin component

Comment: Look: https://imgur.com/PIYd8yE @Ghassen

Comment: The type arguments for method 'DbContext.Set<TEntity>(string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Ah, so the type is unknown at compiletime, right? And there is no `Set( Type )` overload.

Comment: @Fildor the type is already known since he is doing  if (type == typeof(PostEntity))

Comment: Otherwise he has to do with reflection . @SoftwareArchitect can you confirm ?

Comment: @Ghassen With that condition it is still only known _at runtime_. For Generics, Type information must be known at _compile time_.

Comment: yes, i know , i need to understand what is the purpose of this method, i guess the issue is not with ef but  an architectural  issue

Comment: Yes, this is the case. I need extension method which i pass value of @type variable to find EntityType

Answer (score 1):

```
public async Task Accept(int id,Type type)
        {
            if (type == typeof(PostEntity))
            {
                using var factory = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
                var post = await factory.Set<PostEntity>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
                post!.IsVerified = true;
                await factory.SaveChangesAsync();

            }

            }
```

---

Or dynamically by using the Find method :

```
public virtual object Find([NotNull] Type entityType, [CanBeNull] params object[] keyValues)
```

so in the case :

```
public async Task Accept(int id,Type type)
        {
            
                using var factory = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
                dynamic post = contextFactory().Find(type,id)
                post!.IsVerified = true;
                await factory.SaveChangesAsync();

             
        }
```

---

The best solution is :

1. Create a base class BaseEntity (conatins IsVerified , id )
2. Configure it in the context
3. use it to retrieve your item

Comment: i will try this later, as far as compiler said the same.  The type arguments for method 'DbContext.Set<TEntity>(string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.